# How to assign table parameters to use it many times

Tags: list-manipulation, parameters

I'm using two nested `Table` to generate data which depend on two parameters, let's say it is temperature and pressure, many times in my code. When I change the temp and pressure values in calculations, I have to manually change it in all of the nested ``Table```.
Here's simple example:

```
Table[Table[temp + press, {temp, 200, 500, 100}], {press, 1, 4}]
(* Out: {{201, 301, 401, 501}, {202, 302, 402, 502}, {203, 303, 403, 
  503}, {204, 304, 404, 504}} *)
```

Is there any way to define firstly parts of tables `{temp, 200, 500, 100}` and `{press, 1, 4}` and just use it as a variable at all tables? Or any other construct that will help me to avoid changing all the parameters?

I've seen such a code a while ago but I cant find this right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
(* somewhere at the beginning of your code *)
Ts = Range[200,500,100];
ps = Range[1,4];

(* somewhere in the middle of your code -- version 1 *)
Table[T+p,{p,ps},{T,Ts}]

(* somewhere in the middle of your code -- version 2 *)
Table[Table[T+p,{T,Ts}],{p,ps}]
```

This works because one can let iteration variables run over a list, see [the documentation for Table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html).

Comment: Of course, adding a temperature and a pressure is not usually a good idea from the point of view of [units](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html).

Comment: Yes, of course, it is just a simple (and silly, as it turns out :) example, I actually solve kinetic ODE.  Your answer is really helpful, I used iteration over a list many times but I don't know why I haven't got this idea earlier. Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

You may store the iteration variables in some variables and then insert them using "Evaluate". E.g.:

```
te = {temp, 200, 500, 100};
pr = {press, 1, 4};
Table[temp + press, Evaluate@te, Evaluate@pr]

(* {{201, 202, 203, 204}, {301, 302, 303, 304}, {401, 402, 403, 
  404}, {501, 502, 503, 504}}*)
```